# jQuery jerk issue with continuous hover on tabs

Tags: jquery, css

I am facing the issue with jQuery tabs. However the `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` effect is working fine but if user continuously (switching) hover between tabs, the red section try to open and jerk with small red part. How do I fix this issue or make the section fully open or closed and do nothing if user continuously fast hover on tabs.

[**JS FIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/nh0p67tL/1/)

Comment: would it not be a good idea to trigger when they are clicked? Or do you have some sort of constrain?

Comment: do you need slide up slide down animation? or other animation effects is ok?

Comment: Thanks @usrNotFound ! It is working fine if I use click event. But I need to do it with hover effect.

Comment: @MaheswaranS ! only SlideUp and SlideDown

Comment: maybe this might help https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CaptionHoverEffects/index.html it has some css as well to it wont look as bad

Comment: @usrNotFound! I am not good with CSS

Answer (score 1):

took your code :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
        jQuery('.etabs li,.tab_content .etabs_item').mouseenter(function(){
          var _tabid = jQuery(this).data('tab');

          if(jQuery(this).hasClass('no-drop')){
            return false;
          }

          jQuery('.tab_content .etabs_item').stop(true, true).slideUp();
          jQuery("[data-id='"+_tabid+"']").stop(true, true).slideDown(function() { $(this).addClass('no-drop') } );
        });

        $('.tab_content').mouseleave(function(){
                jQuery('.tab_content .etabs_item').stop(true, true).slideUp(function() { $(this).removeClass('no-drop') } );    
        });
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nh0p67tL/3/

added functions at the end of the slide down and slide up events, to add and remove your 'no-drop' class.

Comment: Thanks Stavm! You have added fallback class `no-drop` i.e `return false;`. But now it should be slideUp when we hover on 'NO EFFECT' tab or `mouseleave` from the tabs.